# What are the remaining phenomena Heartseed places on the club members?

Tags: kokoro-connect

The anime & OVAs of Kokoro Connect only cover up to the light novel "Kokoro Connect - Michi Random"

But there are several other novels:

- Kokoro Connect Clip Time
- Kokoro Connect Nise Random
- Kokoro Connect Yume Random
- Kokoro Connect Step Time
- Kokoro Connect Asu Random (volume 1)
- Kokoro Connect Asu Random (volume 2)
- Kokoro Connect Precious Time

The [Wikipedia page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kokoro_Connect#Media) mentions other phenomena, such as "Perspective Dreamland", but this seems to be roughly translated and I have no idea what it entails.

**What phenomena were not covered by the anime, but feature in the Light Novels?**

As an optional side question, Does the manga cover any more phenomena further than the anime?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The anime stops at Michi Random, so the ones that are left over are:
(mostly taken from [The Kokoro Connect Wikia](http://kokoroconnect.wikia.com/wiki/Phenomenons)

*The question obviously can't be answered without any spoilers, so just a small warning*

- Illusion Projection (Nise Random)

  > Grants the user the ability to take on the appearance of anyone. The illusion is just that, a superficial projection rather than a biological change, and the image projected is only seen by the five original members of the StuCS and can only be used on them.
- Forced Termination (Nise Random)

  > Automatically activates in response to two or more people experiencing a paradox as a result of a phenomenon, for example, if two or more people observe the same Illusion Projection at the same time. The ensuing paradox will cause the observers to have their memories reset to before ever encountering Heartseed. Another trigger for this phenomenon is if there is a risk in deteriorating mental state or injury,
- Dream Perception (Yume Random)

  > Allows the club members to perceive the desires, thoughts, and hopes of others which can be summed up as a "dream". The members can only see the "dreams" of people outside of the StuCS and only of people associated with Yamaboshi High; This power activates randomly and somewhat relative to the physical distance between them
- Record Deletion (Asu Random I)

  > Automatically activates during the aftermath of a phenomenon that has ended. All people involved, including Heartseeds, will have all their memories regarding the phenomenon wiped clean. The Cultural Research Club is the only known group to resist this phenomenon, having managed to retain their memories for almost two years. Record Deletion typically kicks in a few weeks after a phenomenon has ended.
- Isolation Dimension (Asu Random I)

  > As its name implies, is an alternate dimension that isolates certain individuals from the normal world. Physically, the dimension looks no different from the norm, but the people in the dimension are completely cut off from those outside of it. In the Isolation Dimension, the Heartseeds can cause their phenomenons without worrying about any detrimental effects on the outside world. As described in Asu Random, it is similar to a laboratory for the Heartseeds to do experimentation
- Several Unnamed Phenomenons (Asu Random II)

  - A Group of Girls From Inaba's Class: One member of the group is randomly made invisible to the other members. The victim cannot be detected by any of the other members' five senses. However, people outside of the group can still acknowledge the target.
  - Gym Group: While the phenomenon is in effect, one member suddenly perceives the other members as frightful, hostile enemies.
  - Ishikawa Daisuke, Watase Shingo, Setouchi Kaoru, Nakayama Mariko: This phenomenon forces each member's likes and dislikes to change in unpredictable ways. For example, Mariko suddenly liked Watase and became affectionate towards him despite being in a relationship with Ishikawa. The emotions that are forced onto them are so strong that it can change their behaviour and even make them do things they normally wouldn't do.
  - Jazz Band Club: At random times, this phenomenon will force a member to tell a lie even if they don't want to.
  - Student Council Executives: Fujishima and the rest of the council experienced a random change in "roles". For example, Fujishima is leader of the Executives, but, when the phenomenon is occurring, she might become the subordinate, following whatever someone else is saying and not voicing an opinion at all.
- Parallel World (Asu Random II)

  > Similar to the Isolation Dimension , all Phenomena have been erased from the StuCS's memories and everyone continued living as if those events never transpired. Things that happen during this phenomen and its results are remembered after it is over and remain.  This phenomenon is a "what if" scenario Heartseed wanted to see.

There's also a non-canon phenomenon - Future Predictions that featured in the PSP game:

> given the power to foresee a prediction of that will happen to a fellow member of the group. They will only see an image and must use the clues in the image to decipher the meaning of the prediction. When the phenomenon activates and which member the prediction is about is completely random. How far into the future the prediction is is also random.